# Programmatically created configurable product doesnt show on frontend

Tags: magento

I have created module that imports products to Magento. It creates both simple and configurable products and adds those simple products to the configurable product. Products are added to their categories by

```
$product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
```

and just in case I also do this

```
    foreach($categoryIds as $i=>$v){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($v, $product->getId());
    }
```

When I look in backend products have their categories checked, also when I look at categories they have their products added too.

So everything looks fine, but when I go on frontend to category, products are missing from there. Then all I have to do is open the configurable product and/or one of its simple products and WITHOUT changing anything I just hit save and then when I go to frontend the product is visible in category.

Ofcourse cashe is disabled and indexing is run after import is done, so no problem there.

**EDIT**

This creates the configurable product.

```
private function createParentProduct($productId){
    if($this->product&&!$productId){//create
        $name=$this->product->sGetName($this->language['value']);
        if(!$name||$name==''){
            return Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->__('failed, missing product name');
        }
        $data=$this->product->sGetData();

        $product = Mage::getModel('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product');
        $product->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE);
        $product->setTaxClassId($this->taxClass['value']);
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $product->setStoreId($this->scope['scopeId']);

        $store=Mage::getModel('Mage_Core_Model_Store')->load($this->scope['scopeId']);
        $product->setWebsiteIDs(array($store->getWebsiteId()));

        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setSku('shirtId-'.$this->product->sGetId());
        $product->setName($name);
        $product->setUrl(Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($name));
        $product->setPrice(floatVal($this->product->sGetPrice($this->language['value'])));
        $product->setCreatedAt(time());
        $product->setDescription($this->product->sGetDescription($this->language['value']));
        $product->setShortDescription($this->product->sGetShortDescription($this->language['value']));

        $product->setData('shirt_artNr', $data['artNr']);
        $product->setShirtModel($data['model']);
        $materials=$this->product->sGetAssignedMaterials();
        $assigMaterials=array();
        foreach($materials as $i=>$v){
            $material=$v->sGetMaterial()->sGetName();
            if(!$material||$material==''){
                continue;
            }
            $assigMaterials[]=$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_material', $material, $v->sGetMaterial()->sGetId());
        }
        $product->setData('shirt_material', $assigMaterials);

        $categoryIds=array();
        $categories=$this->product->sGetAssignedCategories();
        foreach($categories as $i=>$v){
            $category=$v->sGetCategory()->checkIfCategoryExists();
            if($category){
                $categoryIds[]=$category;
            }
        }
        $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);

        $product->setStockData(array(
            //'is_in_stock'=>1,
            //'qty'=>null,
            'manage_stock'=>0,
            'use_config_manage_stock'=>0,
            'use_config_enable_qty_increments'=>0,
            //'use_config_notify_stock_qty'=>0,
            'enable_qty_increments'=>0,
        ));

        $newAttributes=array();
        foreach(array('shirt_color', 'shirt_size') as $attrCode){
            $super_attribute=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product',$attrCode);
            $configurableAtt=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')->setProductAttribute($super_attribute);

            $newAttributes[] = array(
                'id'=>$configurableAtt->getId(),
                'label'=>$configurableAtt->getLabel(),
                'position'=>$super_attribute->getPosition(),
                'values'=>array(),
                'attribute_id'=>$super_attribute->getId(),
                'attribute_code'=>$super_attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                'frontend_label'=>$super_attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
            );
        }

        $configurableData=array();
        $colors=$this->product->sGetAssignedColors();
        $sizes=$this->product->sGetAssignedSizes();
        $simpleProducts=array();
        $colorId=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','shirt_color')->getId();
        $sizeId=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','shirt_size')->getId();
        $filterColors=array();
        $filterSizes=array();
        foreach($colors as $i=>$v){
            $name=$v->sGetColor()->sGetName($this->language['value']);
            if(in_array($name, $filterColors)){
                unset($colors[$i]);
            }else{
                $filterColors[]=$name;

                $newAttributes[0]['values'][]=array(
                    'value_index'=>0,
                    'label'=>$name,
                    'is_percent'=>0,
                    'pricing_value'=>'0',
                    'attribute_id'=>$colorId,
                );
            }
        }
        foreach($sizes as $i=>$v){
            $name=$v->sGetSize()->sGetName($this->language['value']);
            if(in_array($name, $filterSizes)){
                unset($sizes[$i]);
            }else{
                $filterSizes[]=$name;

                $newAttributes[1]['values'][]=array(
                    'value_index'=>0,
                    'label'=>$name,
                    'is_percent'=>0,
                    'pricing_value'=>'0',
                    'attribute_id'=>$sizeId,
                );
            }
        }
        foreach($colors as $i=>$v){
            foreach($sizes as $si=>$sv){
                $clone=null;
                $clone=clone $product;
                $id=$this->createSimpleProduct($clone, $v->sGetColor(), $sv->sGetSize());
                $simpleProducts[$id]=$id;

                $configurableData[$id]=array();
                $configurableData[$id][]=array(
                    'attribute_id'=>$colorId,
                    'label'=>$v->sGetColor()->sGetName($this->language['value']),
                    'value_index'=>$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_color', $v->sGetColor()->sGetName($this->language['value']), $v->sGetColor()->sGetId()),
                );
                $configurableData[$id][]=array(
                    'attribute_id'=>$sizeId,
                    'label'=>$sv->sGetSize()->sGetName($this->language['value']),
                    'value_index'=>$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_size', $sv->sGetSize()->sGetName($this->language['value']), $sv->sGetSize()->sGetId()),
                );
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($newAttributes); echo "</pre>"; exit;
        $product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableData);
        $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($newAttributes);
        $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(1);

        $product->save();

        foreach($categoryIds as $i=>$v){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($v, $product->getId());
        }

        $key='importProduct_'.$this->product->sGetId();
        $setting=serialize(array(
            'magentoId'=>$product->getId(),
            'time'=>time()
        ));
        Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin')->saveSetting(Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->getCurrentAdminScope(), $key, $setting);
        $this->return=Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->__('created configurable product with %d simple products', count($simpleProducts));
        return intVal($product->getId());
    }elseif($this->product&&$productId){//update
        $name=$this->product->sGetName($this->language['value']);
        if(!$name||$name==''){
            return Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->__('failed, missing product name');
        }
        $data=$this->product->sGetData();

        $product = Mage::getModel('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product')->load($productId);
        $product->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE);
        $product->setTaxClassId($this->taxClass['value']);
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $product->setStoreId($this->scope['scopeId']);

        $store=Mage::getModel('Mage_Core_Model_Store')->load($this->scope['scopeId']);
        $product->setWebsiteIDs(array($store->getWebsiteId()));

        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setSku('shirtId-'.$this->product->sGetId());
        $product->setName($name);
        $product->setUrl(Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($name));
        $product->setPrice(floatVal($this->product->sGetPrice($this->language['value'])));
        $product->setCreatedAt(time());
        $product->setDescription($this->product->sGetDescription($this->language['value']));
        $product->setShortDescription($this->product->sGetShortDescription($this->language['value']));

        $product->setData('shirt_artNr', $data['artNr']);
        $product->setShirtModel($data['model']);
        $materials=$this->product->sGetAssignedMaterials();
        $assigMaterials=array();
        foreach($materials as $i=>$v){
            $material=$v->sGetMaterial()->sGetName();
            if(!$material||$material==''){
                continue;
            }
            $assigMaterials[]=$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_material', $material, $v->sGetMaterial()->sGetId());
        }
        $product->setData('shirt_material', $assigMaterials);

        $categoryIds=array();
        $categories=$this->product->sGetAssignedCategories();
        foreach($categories as $i=>$v){
            $category=$v->sGetCategory()->checkIfCategoryExists();
            if($category){
                $categoryIds[]=$category;
            }
        }
        $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);

        $newAttributes=array();
        foreach(array('shirt_color', 'shirt_size') as $attrCode){
            $super_attribute=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product',$attrCode);
            $configurableAtt=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')->setProductAttribute($super_attribute);

            $newAttributes[] = array(
                'id'=>$configurableAtt->getId(),
                'label'=>$configurableAtt->getLabel(),
                'position'=>$super_attribute->getPosition(),
                'values'=>array(),
                'attribute_id'=>$super_attribute->getId(),
                'attribute_code'=>$super_attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                'frontend_label'=>$super_attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
            );
        }

        $configurableData=array();
        $colors=$this->product->sGetAssignedColors();
        $sizes=$this->product->sGetAssignedSizes();
        $simpleProducts=array();
        $colorId=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','shirt_color')->getId();
        $sizeId=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','shirt_size')->getId();
        $filterColors=array();
        $filterSizes=array();
        foreach($colors as $i=>$v){
            $name=$v->sGetColor()->sGetName($this->language['value']);
            if(in_array($name, $filterColors)){
                unset($colors[$i]);
            }else{
                $filterColors[]=$name;
            }
        }
        foreach($sizes as $i=>$v){
            $name=$v->sGetSize()->sGetName($this->language['value']);
            if(in_array($name, $filterSizes)){
                unset($sizes[$i]);
            }else{
                $filterSizes[]=$name;
            }
        }
        foreach($colors as $i=>$v){
            foreach($sizes as $si=>$sv){
                $clone=null;
                $clone=clone $product;
                $id=$this->createSimpleProduct($clone, $v->sGetColor(), $sv->sGetSize());
                $simpleProducts[$id]=$id;

                $configurableData[$id]=array();
                $configurableData[$id][]=array(
                    'attribute_id'=>$colorId,
                    'label'=>$v->sGetColor()->sGetName($this->language['value']),
                    'value_index'=>$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_color', $v->sGetColor()->sGetName($this->language['value']), $v->sGetColor()->sGetId()),
                );
                $configurableData[$id][]=array(
                    'attribute_id'=>$sizeId,
                    'label'=>$sv->sGetSize()->sGetName($this->language['value']),
                    'value_index'=>$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_size', $sv->sGetSize()->sGetName($this->language['value']), $sv->sGetSize()->sGetId()),
                );
            }
        }
        $product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableData);
        //$product->setConfigurableAttributesData($newAttributes);//Shouldnt be needed here in update, but might need future modification
        $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(1);

        $product->save();

        foreach($categoryIds as $i=>$v){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($v, $product->getId());
        }

        $key='importProduct_'.$this->product->sGetId();
        $setting=serialize(array(
            'magentoId'=>$product->getId(),
            'time'=>time()
        ));
        Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin')->saveSetting(Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->getCurrentAdminScope(), $key, $setting);
        $this->return=Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->__('updated configurable product with %d simple products', count($simpleProducts));
        return intVal($product->getId());
    }
}
```

And here is simple product.

```
private function createSimpleProduct($product, $color, $size){
    $productId=$this->checkIfSimpleProductExists($this->product, $color, $size);
    if(!$productId){//create
        $product->setName($this->product->sGetName($this->language['value']).'-'.$color->sGetName($this->language['value']).'-'.$size->sGetName($this->language['value']));
        $product->setUrl(Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($product->getName()));
        $product->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
        $product->setSku('shirtId-'.$this->product->sGetId().'-'.Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($color->sGetName($this->language['value'])).'-'.Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($size->sGetName($this->language['value'])));
        $product->setWeight(0);

        $product->setData('shirt_color', $this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_color', $color->sGetName($this->language['value'])), $color->sGetId());
        $product->setData('shirt_size', $this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_size', $size->sGetName($this->language['value'])), $size->sGetId());

        $product->save();

        foreach($categoryIds as $i=>$v){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($v, $product->getId());
        }

        $key='importProduct_'.$this->product->sGetId().'_'.$color->sGetId().'_'.$size->sGetId();
        $setting=serialize(array(
            'magentoId'=>$product->getId(),
            'time'=>time()
        ));
        Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin')->saveSetting(Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->getCurrentAdminScope(), $key, $setting);
    }else{//update
        $data=$this->product->sGetData();
        $product=Mage::getModel('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product')->load($productId);

        $product->setName($this->product->sGetName($this->language['value']).'-'.$color->sGetName($this->language['value']).'-'.$size->sGetName($this->language['value']));
        $product->setUrl(Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($product->getName()));
        $product->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
        $product->setSku('shirtId-'.$this->product->sGetId().'-'.Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($color->sGetName($this->language['value'])).'-'.Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin_Import')->removeDiacritic($size->sGetName($this->language['value'])));
        $product->setWeight(0);
        $product->setDescription($this->product->sGetDescription($this->language['value']));
        $product->setShortDescription($this->product->sGetShortDescription($this->language['value']));

        $product->setData('shirt_artNr', $data['artNr']);
        $product->setShirtModel($data['model']);
        $materials=$this->product->sGetAssignedMaterials();
        $assigMaterials=array();
        foreach($materials as $i=>$v){
            $material=$v->sGetMaterial()->sGetName();
            if(!$material||$material==''){
                continue;
            }
            $assigMaterials[]=$this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_material', $material, $v->sGetMaterial()->sGetId());
        }
        $product->setData('shirt_material', $assigMaterials);
        $product->setData('shirt_color', $this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_color', $color->sGetName($this->language['value'])), $color->sGetId());
        $product->setData('shirt_size', $this->addNewValueToAttribute('shirt_size', $size->sGetName($this->language['value'])), $size->sGetId());

        $categoryIds=array();
        $categories=$this->product->sGetAssignedCategories();
        foreach($categories as $i=>$v){
            $category=$v->sGetCategory()->checkIfCategoryExists();
            if($category){
                $categoryIds[]=$category;
            }
        }
        $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);

        $product->save();

        foreach($categoryIds as $i=>$v){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($v, $product->getId());
        }

        $key='importProduct_'.$this->product->sGetId().'_'.$color->sGetId().'_'.$size->sGetId();
        $setting=serialize(array(
            'magentoId'=>$product->getId(),
            'time'=>time()
        ));
        Mage::getModel('PSDCoding_Shirtplugin_Model_Shirtplugin')->saveSetting(Mage::helper('shirtplugin')->getCurrentAdminScope(), $key, $setting);
    }
    if($product->getId()){
        return $product->getId();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be an error in the php code that creates the products. Could you post some more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that Magento didnt update stock status. So when you create product programmatically dont forget to add at least:

```
$stockStatus = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status');
$stockStatus->assignProduct($product);
$stockStatus->saveProductStatus($product->getId(), 1);
```

It is also good to create stock item object and use category api to assign products.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems like the products are fine and it's merely a problem of visibility:

```
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
// why VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE?
```

is that intended? should be visible by default.

If that does not work check your values for:

```
$product->setWebsiteIDs(...) and $product->setStoreId(...)
```

Comment: If you look at what I wrote, all of this is ok. I dont change any of this when I got to backend, I just hit "save". Visibility, storeId, websiteId are all ok.

Comment: I read that, but as your product creation code does not seem to miss anything, the "save" in the backend changes something. Are the products toggled visible in the backend? (see the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE question)

Comment: No the visibility does not change in the backend. Config is still Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH and simple products are Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE. Im lost/confused too, it should be all ok, but at the same time it isnt. Have been trying to solve it for more than day and yet nothing works.

Comment: maybe the stock keeping is your problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137413/programmatically-created-configurable-item-doesnt-show-options-until-i-manually

Comment: Will look at that. There is one thing however that it does, but only sometimes, so Im not sure If it is relevant. Sometimes after I import products the Product Prices Index doesnt reindex and shows server error, it only reindexes after I delete imported products. Maybe Im doing something wrong with simple products prices when added to configurable product?

Comment: The stock status was the problem, it works now. Pity that it didnt show in google/stack search results for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I have faced earlier. Reindex all solved my issue. You can also try.

Comment: Tried that both manually and also I have it in code, so that it reindexes all after import. But sometimes price index doent finish and show server error. Works only after I delete all those products that I have imported.